# How to format LaTeX formulas with double dollar signs (`$$`) in PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, escaping, string-literals

I am building a PostgreSQL query through a script that returns formatted LaTeX formulas surrounded by double dollar signs, such as the following one:

```
$$6 x^{14} + \frac{7 x^{13}}{5} + \frac{13 x^{8}}{7} + \frac{5 x^{5}}{6}$$
```

Moreover, these formulas belong to an array, so that the complete `INSERT` query would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table("array")
VALUES (
'{"$$6 x^{14} + \frac{7 x^{13}}{5} + \frac{13 x^{8}}{7} + \frac{5 x^{5}}{6}$$",
"$$\frac{9 x^{11}}{13} + \frac{13 x^{9}}{7} + x^{8} + \frac{x^{6}}{3}$$",
"$$2 x^{13} + \frac{52 x^{12}}{3} + \frac{65 x^{4}}{9} + \frac{3}{2}$$"}'
)
```

However, following the INSERT, the backslash (`\`) that precedes `frac` disappears in the database (I get `frac` instead of `\frac`. Consequently my formulas do not render well in my application.

Here's the content of the cell:

```
{"$$6 x^{14} + frac{7 x^{13}}{5} + frac{13 x^{8}}{7} + frac{5 x^{5}}{6}$$",
"$$frac{9 x^{11}}{13} + frac{13 x^{9}}{7} + x^{8} + frac{x^{6}}{3}$$",
"$$2 x^{13} + frac{52 x^{12}}{3} + frac{65 x^{4}}{9} + frac{3}{2}$$"}
```

I use the [sympy module](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) in Python to automatically generate the formulas, so to manually double the backslashes before each `frac` is **not** an option.

What should I do to prevent this behavior from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash is an escape character in strings that represent an array of strings:

```
SELECT ('{a,"b\"c\\d"}'::text[])[2];
 text  
-------
 b"c\d
(1 row)
```

If the backslash does not precede a character with a special meaning, it is ignored.

Double all the backslashes inside the string representation of a string array in PostgreSQL to get what you want.

If such backslashes are the only ones occurring in your string constant, you could proceed as follows:

```
SELECT replace(
          '{"$$6 x^{14} + \frac{7 x^{13}}{5} + \frac{13 x^{8}}{7} + \frac{5 x^{5}}{6}$$",
           "$$\frac{9 x^{11}}{13} + \frac{13 x^{9}}{7} + x^{8} + \frac{x^{6}}{3}$$",
           "$$2 x^{13} + \frac{52 x^{12}}{3} + \frac{65 x^{4}}{9} + \frac{3}{2}$$"}',
          '\',
          '\\'
       )::text[];
```

Comment: I think it would be nice to add to your answer how to automatically include the needed backslashes, as the question states that manually adding the backslashes wouldn't be an option. Assuming sympy will return raw strings one could use stringname.replace('\\', '\\') to get the new string with added backslashes.

Comment: The weird thing is that a cell content such as `'Hello $$\frac{x^{11}}{10} + \frac{4 x^{6}}{7}$$'` is accepted without any problem. The single backslash is preserved in this case. I suspected that it is because the `$$` doesn't appear at the beginning of the line, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Anyway, I could implement a workaround as you suggested through a `str()` cast and the `replace('\\', '\\\\')` method.

Comment: I have added how you can use `replace` in SQL for that.

Comment: Re-reading the answer the point seems to be that there is a different interpretation of the backslash in string VS array of strings. Would anyone be able to confirm?